# Map outgoing TCP connection to Docker container

Tags: docker, tcpdump

I have a collection of IPv4 traffic recorded by tcpdump, and I am interested in mapping a given outgoing connection to its origin Docker container on the same machine. I can view the TCP source port, but it is unclear to me how to ask Docker which container is using this port. How can this be done?
Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You can [filter](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/commandline/ps/#filtering) containers which publish or expose a given port:

```
docker ps --filter=expose=3306
```

or use the [format](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/commandline/ps/#formatting) switch to get a list of container IDs with the used ports:

```
docker ps --format "{{.ID}}: {{.Ports}}"
```

Comment: Thank you for your reply. The above commands are indeed very useful, but they show the ports that a given container is **listening to**, not the port being used by docker for traffic originating in the container.

Answer (score 0):

I had this exact problem where I wanted to know which container was the client for a particular Postgresql database query. These are the steps I took to find the container that was the source of the TCP connection I was interested in.

In postgres query `pg_stat_activity` to determine the `client_addr` and `client_port` of the query you care about:

```
SELECT * FROM pg_stat_activity;
```

Now you know the source ip (`client_addr`) you can ssh to this box and determine the network interface used by docker:

```
ip addr
```

In my case it was `docker0`. Now we can use the source port of the database connection (`client_port`) to find the container ip address:

```
tcpdump -i docker0 src port 52282
 02:41:16.257106 IP 172.17.0.15.52282 > 192.168.2.119.postgres: Flags [P.] ...
```

Now we need to work out which container this source ip (`172.17.0.15`) belongs to, to do this we can use the docker inspect command with a filter:

```
docker inspect -f '{{range .NetworkSettings.Networks}}{{.IPAddress}}{{end}}' container
```

We run this command in a loop for each of the running containers and grep for the ip we are looking for:

```
for name in $( docker ps --format '{{.Names}}' ); do echo -n "$name => " && docker inspect -f '{{range .NetworkSettings.Networks}}{{.IPAddress}}{{end}}' $name; done | grep 172.17.0.15
my-container => 172.17.0.15
```

Now we know that the container `my-container` is the source of the traffic we are interested in.